# Not quite straight lines; any help in Aperture?

Tags: apple-aperture, distortion

[image: Possible distortion?]

This slightly bent sculpture is, I imagine, suffering from a bit of distortion. I thought that the raw processor in Aperture included lens data to correct this; the lens in question is a 55-200 Nikon DX. Is this correctable in Aperture? If so how?

Comment: Apple is discontinuing development of Aperture, so you'll have to switch eventually, it might be time to consider switching to Lightroom, which does have lens corrections built in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Aperture doesn't have built in automatic lens distortion- you need to buy the plugin PTLens, ~$25.